# Dynamic Type for List

Tags: c#, list

I am having line like this

```
gridTable = (targetGrid.DataSource as List<Proizvod>).ConvertToDataTable();
```

Now I want to change that code to pass `List<T>` based on `targetGrid.DataSource` type.

So if I assigned `List<Proizvod>` to `targetGrid.DataSource` above line should look like it is but if I passed `List<Order>` it should look like

```
gridTable = (targetGrid.DataSource as List<Order>).ConvertToDataTable();
```

I tried a lot of thing like

```
(targetGrid.DataSource as IList)
(targetGrid.DataSource as IList<>)
(targetGrid.DataSource as object)
```

passing `Type datatype` to my function and then using it like

```
(targetGrid.DataSource as List<datatype>)
```

and a lot of other things I found on internet and which I came up with but all of them didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to use reflection. I have linked to a question which shows how to do that. Note that you will have to use the "classic" syntax to refer to your extension method in that case.

Comment: what type is `targetGrid` ? `DataGridView` ?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes it is